# How to pass value from custom directive to custom filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list and want it to filter by my custom filter. But the value to it I want to put from custom directive with it's own scope. How to do it?
Body:

```
<body ng-controller="test">
 <tr ng-repeat="item in list | myfilter: HowToPuttHereValue? >
```

Here is my custom filter:

```
 .filter('myfilter', function(){
         return function(array, num){
                return array.slice(num, num+1);    
         }
})
```

And here is my custom directive:

```
 .directive('mydirective', function() {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template:"<input ng-model='counter'><button ng-click='getIt(counter)'>PRESS</button>",
            scope:{
                item: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attr){

                scope.getIt = function(counter){
                console.log(counter);
                }     
            }
        }
    })
```

Please see the Example:
[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4b4US/274/)

P.S. I guess I've already found a solution using "scope.$parent" . But is there a possibility to pass the value straight to a "myfilter: here? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/Laf69pja/).

```
<div ng-app="hello">
    <div ng-controller="forExampleController">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="num in list | myfilter: howToPutHereFromDirective ">{{num}} </li>
        </ul>

        <mydirective item="list.length" filter-value="howToPutHereFromDirective"></mydirective>
    </div>    


</div>
```

---

```
function forExampleController($scope){
  $scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    $scope.howToPutHereFromDirective = 3;
}

angular.module('hello', [])
     .filter('myfilter', function(){
         return function(array, num){

             return array.slice(num, num+1);

         }
})
     .directive('mydirective', function() {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template:"<input ng-model='counter'><button ng-click='getIt()'>PRESS</button>",
            scope:{
                item: '=',
                filterValue: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attr){

                scope.getIt = function(){
                    scope.filterValue = parseInt(scope.counter);
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Doing `scope.$parent` within isolated scope isn't too good indeed, because the objective of isolated scope is exactly the opposite.

I'm not sure what purpose `item="list.length"` two-way binding has to serve, but it is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, this solution is also interesting. Also thanks for correcting the item="list.length" situation.